# Whitespaces in filepath causing problems (windows shell and python)

Tags: python, cmd, whitespace, pyinstaller, windows-shell

I'm making a program that transforms `.py` files into `.exe` files. I got it working correctly, but I find that the program fails if there are any spaces in the file path. This path would fail, for example:

```
 C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\Python\Python to Exe - Tkinter - Pyinstaller\py2exe.py
```

Specifically, this fails whenever it is passed to the windows shell, since it cannot take filepaths with whitespaces. This is the command that fails on cmd:

```
 pyinstaller C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\Python\Python to Exe - Tkinter - Pyinstaller\Py2Exe.py
```

What would be a workaround to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting quotes around it should fix your problem.

```
"C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\Python\Python to Exe - Tkinter - Pyinstaller\py2exe.py"
```

Answer (score 3):

Either double quote the path, or escape it:

```
"C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\Python\Python to Exe - Tkinter - Pyinstaller\py2exe.py"
```

Escaping:

```
C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\Python\Python\ to\ Exe\ -\ Tkinter\ -\ Pyinstaller\py2exe.py
```